# how do you make a password generator in command prompt that uses letters?

Tags: passwords, auto-generate, letters, cmp

I know how to create a password generator in command prompt but it only uses numbers. Is there a way to make it generate letters as well? for example, ASDE-DASD-DWAS-AWDS.

Comment: Could you share some code with how you're doing it for numbers?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this the Windows command prompt?

Comment: yeah sorry about that it is windows. here is the code for the generator

Comment: @echo off
:password
echo %random%- %random%- %random%
pause
goto password

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Linux, try this:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | head -c8
```

Change the last number (8 here) to be how many digits you want.

I have no idea what you're using this for, but this does work. There may be better ways to do what you really want to do.

Comment: sorry I always forget to mention the OS it is windows vista. why I want to make a generator in cmp is so that I can use it on my friends computer but his com is slow so I don't want to install a program for it.